# Ошибка The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K

Tags: android

При попытке запустить проект, столкнулся со следующими 2-мя ошибками:

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>   Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForOkhttpDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

После того как загуглил свою первую ошибку, нашёл интересное [поздравление](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) на оффициальном сайте:

> If you have built an Android app and received this error, then congratulations, you have a lot of code!

Но как быть, если моё приложение на самом деле не такое уж громозкое и в подключении multidex явно не нуждается.

Comment: Речь же не только о вашем коде, но и коде всех подключенных библиотек. За них можете ручаться?

Comment: @D-side да конечно, более Вам скажу, что данное приложение долгое время не запускал и до этого работало всё корректно. Да и библиотек там не так то и много на самом деле.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Установите [dexcount-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin), он покажет, кто и сколько методов использует, сгенерить html в папку build.
- Проинспектируйте свой код, возможно от некоторых библиотек можно избавиться, например от guava (14,842). Google Play Services(29,460) не стоит подключать все сразу.
- Примените `proguard`, который уберет неиспользуемый код.

Если ничего не поможет, используйте `multidex`

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

---

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ....
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

---

```
package ....;
...
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
  ....
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
    MultiDex.install(this);
   }
}
```

---

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Я сразу решил установить mulitdex. Так как с proguard'ом еще не работал так тесно,а подключать плагины тоже как то не хотелось. Но вот вопрос, Вы указали что от некоторых библиотек можно избавиться, а именно GooglePlay Services. Но как быть если я использую в своём приложении карты, и они просто не будут работать.

Comment: @Morozov вероятно вы подключили всю библиотеку, когда вам нужна только карта. Покажите app/gradle.build .

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0' , просто знаю что так подключают библиотеку.

Comment: @Morozov попробуйте так     `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'`

Comment: приставками -maps и -locations я так понимаю мы берем только интересующие нас пакеты, а не целиком библиотеку? с 9.6.1 не получилось запустить, обновился до 9.8.0 работает корректно.